# Complex integral using Cauchy's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle with centre 0 and radius 1.

I got the singularities of this as $(-1+i)$ and $(-1-i)$. And as the modulus of these is $\sqrt2$ they fall outside $\gamma$ so by Cauchy's Theorem this integral is 0. Does that look correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Yep. The quadratic formula gives $\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{-4}/2},$ which are the roots you've given. Thus, the function is holomorphic on the disc, so Cauchy's theorem says that the integral is 0, as the path is homologous to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitively true. Your map is holomorphic "inside" and on the image of $\gamma$.